# How can I make my Legendary Crossbowdwarf stand down?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Note, I am playing an old succession game using version 40d.

I have a legendary Marksdwarf. I stationed him where he needed to be using <kbd>x</kbd> > <kbd>s</kbd>. The seige is over, the goblins are routed, but Fikod won't stand down. I can reassign him, but if I go to the milita screen (<kbd>m</kbd>), I can't deactivate him using <kbd>a</kbd> like I could with all of the other dwarves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Legendary military dwarfs cannot be deactivated. This is a game feature, as those dwarfs have adapted to the militia life and are no longer willing to work as mere civilians. If you want to make sure they're not running around murdering things at a whim, you could station them somewhere or have them training other recruits. This is why you should make sure your important craftsdwarfs don't reach legendary level in weapons skills.

Comment: So once I've stationed a Legendary Militia member, can he do anything besides stand around? Is there a way to cancel the <kbd>x</kbd> > <kbd>s</kbd> order?

Comment: I believe legendary militia members work the same as normal ones, except they can't be deactivated. You should be able to cancel direct orders like normal. I tried to find official references to this feature, but couldn't find anything at first glance.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, how do I cancel a direct order?

Comment: @aslum - It's been a long while, but the wiki says "Pressing the 'o' key in the squad screen will cancel the selected dwarves' active orders, sending them back to their civilian or pre-scheduled military lives." (For a legendary militia dwarf, only the "pre-scheduled military" part applies.) I'm assuming you're playing the most recent version of Dwarf Fort.

Comment: No, playing 40d as I mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: @aslum - Aaah, I'm sorry, I missed that. Everything else still holds except cancelling the command. I think you can only override the command by issuing another, since d40 was pre-militia-overhaul.